# Escape the value of a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell, escaping

how can I make the following work?:

```
var="-e"  #is entered by a user
echo $var  #should produce "-e" but does not, as the string is not escaped
```

The "-e" could for example be passed as input argument $1.

Thanks already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `printf`.
For example:

```
var="-e"
printf %s "$var"
```

should print out -e.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want:

```
echo "${var}"
```

http://kvz.io/blog/2013/11/21/bash-best-practices/

Comment: That does not really give me a difference :/  it still won't show "-e"